# How to start an X.org desktop session manually?

Tags: debian, desktop-environment

For example, I have these sessions:
`ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 268 май 20  2017 cinnamon2d.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 155 май 20  2017 cinnamon.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  86 авг  6  2011 lightdm-xsession.desktop
```

A want to disable GUI by `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`
and after that (after reboot) run manually one of my desktops:

How will I do that?

P.S. My Distro:

```
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
Kernel: Linux 4.9.0-7-amd64
Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `startx` as command or is this a more in-depth problem?

Comment: I want run: cinnamon2d OR cinnamon OR lightdm-xsession. HOW?

Comment: Run `startx`. It will start the Xserver and bring up your display manager.

Comment: sudo startx - `comman not found`. I am in minimalistic debian. Another options?

Comment: Do you have `xinit` installed? `startx` would work without `sudo`. Do you have display managers installed?

Comment: That is shown in your question, yes. lightdm it is. So what about `xinit`? (`dpkg -l xinit`?)

Comment: `xinit` don't exist, but after this command `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` desktop loads fine, so i need load the desktop manually , without "startx", "xinit" , or other additional utilities  ...

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
Xorg &
DISPLAY=:0 exec $(awk -F = '/^Exec/{print $2}' /usr/share/xsessions/cinnamon2d.desktop)
```

Alternatively as an executable bash script:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

SESSDIR=/usr/share/xsessions
test ! -e "$SESSDIR/$1" && echo "Need a valid session to start, [$SESSDIR/$1] doesn't exist" && exit
pgrep Xorg > /dev/null || Xorg &
DISPLAY=:0 exec $(awk -F = '/^Exec/{print $2}' "$SESSDIR/$1")
```

Under Debian 9 you'll need to change `Xorg &` to `sudo Xorg &` and add yourself to sudoers. Otherwise it [all works](https://www60.zippyshare.com/v/f4rdbjeb/file.html) as expected.

Comment: Check the syntax, please

Comment: Fixed..........

Comment: can i run this via script ? Need root? What do `'/^Exec/{print $2}'` ?

Comment: I've just provided the script. Root is not required on sufficiently modern distros. What?

Comment: After run script - `Could not connect to session bus: /usr/bin/dbus-launch treminated abnormally without any error message`. Also if i run `/usr/sbin/lightdm` - same message. I can run `lightdm` normally only via `service lightdm start`. Here the service file: https://codeshare.io/5RPp3W

Comment: Может через мессенджер-телеграм? )

Comment: Works here just fine in Fedora 33. I don't know what your distro is and I cannot really help further. The script is 100% correct. :-( Can you please upload whatever session's desktop file you want to run this way to pastebin.com?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nVqLfHjq

Comment: Repeat: Also if i run `sudo /usr/sbin/lightdm` - same message. I can run lightdm normally only via `sudo service lightdm` start.

Comment: You can't run `lightdm` this way - it is a display manager, it requires root permissions. Only complete sessions can be run this way. I'm not sure why `cinnamon2d` refuses to work. In theory it must.

Comment: Ok, i edited comment. Nevermind. To begin with, how to start  `lightdm`?. Me not care, because the problem is general.

Comment: Please specify your distro and its version and add the info to your question.

Comment: look the updated question

Comment: I've verified my solution works under Debian 9, you only have to start Xorg using sudo, e.g. `sudo Xorg &`